# Should we have a "comic relief" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In my first question on the site, I created the tag [comic-relief](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comic-relief).

It was [edited out](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/44/revisions), because a user thought it wasn't needed. The edit comment was "I've really on the fence about this, but it's a not needed IMO, so I'm nuking it".

I could edit it back in, but I'd rather ask what the community thinks.

On the one hand, I think comic relief is a device in storytelling. I imagine someone would be interested in its use in literature, and would like to filter questions and answers on the subject.

On the other hand, maybe there aren't that many questions on the subject? I don't think it is used very often in literature, at least not in textual literature.

So, I'm looking for community consensus. Should we have a tag for comic relief?

Comment: I'd say yes, but I can't think of a full-fledged answer now.

Comment: @Mithrandir I'm kind of on the fence about it. I want to say yes, but for some reason, I just can't see the relationship between "comic relief" and the question. It's almost tangential at best, because the question isn't about "comic relief" as used in a story. Maybe a [character-development] tag?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I mean, yes, the tag would be useful, just maybe not for *this* question.

Comment: @Zizouz212 The trope is not character development. These characters become suddenly capable when the plot calls for it. But their capability disappears equally quickly and is conveniently forgotten/ignored later on. I had "comic-relief-character" too, but that was edited out earlier. (By the same editor, I see now).

Comment: @VixenPopuli Hmm... I feel that the question isn't about [comic-relief] though. It's about a character almost developing in some way. Personally, I just don't see the "comic relief" part.

Comment: I feel that comic relief is a common literary element, from The Porter in Macbeth to Ron Weasley. We may not get many questions about it, but I would expect them to come.

Answer (score 5):

[comic-relief](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comic-relief) as a tag doesn't fit the question.

The use of the tag in the question was kind of tangential. Comic relief as a subject? Yeah. But there isn't a relationship between comic relief and the question.

May I recommend adding the [character-development](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) tag instead? It more accurately describes what the question is about.

Comment: Next meta post: "should we have a [tag:character-development] tag?"

Comment: @Randal'Thor Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score -5):

I have no objection to a `comedy` tag. However, [*Comic Relief*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_Relief) is the name of a well-known British charity, and this may cause some confusion if a `comic-relief` tag is created.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but we can't go on about how anything can be a tag. This site is a site about literature - tags will be viewed within that context. Am I not allowed to make a tag [liberalism] if I ask a question about a political essay, simply because there are many political parties with that word as part of their name (e.g. Liberal Party of Canada)? Tags have to be viewed in context, we can't worry if some unrelated organization/topic shares the same name.